# Don't skip lists have the same limitation as arrays?

Tags: algorithm, list, data-structures, skip-lists

Would I be right in saying, Skip Lists like arrays can be very efficient if one knows the 'n' (number of elements to  be stored) beforehand?

Maxlevel of a skip list is `(log n + 1)`, and since I need to know  the maxlevel before creating the skip list it means I should  have an idea of what could  be the number of elements that are gonna be stored.

Comment: One nice feature of skip lists is that the maxlevel can be increased dynamically.

Comment: Now wouldn't that be same as dynamically changing the array size?

Comment: Sure, though the reallocation is only logarithmic for skip lists, as opposed to linear for arrays. A relatively low value of `n` will cover all practical situations. For example for `p = 0.5`, a value of `n = 64` will be more than sufficient for a 64-bit processor. It will take you centuries to generate enough data to fill a 64-bit address space.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the max level of a skiplist before you create it, as long as you are prepared to dynamically resize the head, whose size is precisely `maxlevel`. Since `maxlevel` is approximately `log N`, resizing the head happens rarely and when it does happen, it involves very little work. If you really wanted to avoid even that, you could initially create the head with a capacity sufficient for the entire available storage, although that would be a waste of space if most of your skiplists were a few hundred elements.

This all works because the search procedure for a skiplist never moves up a level; only down. So inserting a new node with a higher level than any existing node does not require modifying any existing node except the head, which must be modified to point to the new node at its highest level. (Otherwise, the new level will be useless.)

As a curious implementation detail, it's not necessary to store the size of a node; the fact that a node is pointed to at level `i` is sufficient to demonstrate that the node has at least `i` levels, so there is never any need to compare `i` with the size of the node. Only the size of the head needs to be known.

Answer (score 0):

maxlevel can be dynamically increased.

use `maxlevel=2^(n-1)` for the first (2^n-1) nodes. when the 2^n node come, it is assigned with `level=2^n`, and the next 2^n...2^(n+1) nodes use `maxlevel=2^n`.